# Swift : present a ViewController while alert is shown

Tags: ios, swift, alert, viewcontroller

I have a problem with present UIViewController Modaly by above code

```
self.presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

it doesn't work when another view present modaly such as UIAlert,its triggered by a socket packet in background and user may is performing another work and may another modal view already presented when the trigger happens.

Comment: Is the presenting view controller in the view hierarchy? Have you tried presenting the on the rootViewController of the key window of the application?

Comment: YEP, And its the right way that i didn't check, thank you @Adeel

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @Adeel presenting on `rootViewController` of the `keyWindow` will also not work, 'coz when you `present` any view controller, it makes another window for itself.

Comment: @Hosein, you could add your view controller's view to the `keyWindow` as subview, but that has a few drawbacks. Another way to solve this issue would be keeping reference for the topmost view controller, and present your triggered view controller on that vc, but i'm not sure how you could handle it when alert view is the topmost vc.

Comment: @Adeel Thanks a lot guys , it was my fault it fixed it by use `var window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
                    window.rootViewController = view;
                    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
`

Comment: @FahriAzimov im not sure that can we presentViewController on uiAlertController, but i fixed the problem by presenting the View as rootViewController in window of the application. its work event on alert

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not present two view controllers at the same time from the same source controller. Instead, try presenting the second view controller from the first one that was presented.

```
       if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.present(vcToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            self.present(vcToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```